# What are android's layouts/methods used for creating a Screen like that?

Tags: android

I try and try to search google, but I cannot find the answer for my problem.
I want to create a view (A) in front of current view (B). Then, user can press a button (example: backButton): view A will disappear but the screen still will show view B. It looks like a view that shows up when player loses flappy bird game.

http://imageshack.com/a/img836/4527/giql1.jpg.

Could you let me know the name of this problem and how to solve it without external library?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use either a `FrameLayout` or a `Dialog`. You can read about FrameLayouts here: http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/10/10/framelayout-your-best-ui-friend/

Comment: I used to use Dialog, but it don't support create a table layout on it. Thanks! I will try FrameLayout.

Comment: You can use whatever custom view you want in an `AlertDialog`